# C release dynamically allocated memory

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, free

I have defined function, which returns multidimensional array.

allocation for rows

```
arr = (char **)malloc(size);
```

allocation for columns (in loop)

```
arr[i] = (char *)malloc(v);
```

and returning type is char**

Everything works fine, except freeing the memory. If I call free(arr[i]) and/or free(arr) on array returned by function, it crashes.

EDIT:

allocating function

```
pole = malloc(zaznamov);  
char ulica[52], t[52], datum[10];  
float dan;  
int i = 0, v;
*max = 0;
while (!is_eof(f))
{
    get_record(t, ulica, &dan, datum, f);
    v = strlen(ulica);
pole[i] = malloc(v);
strcpy(pole[i], ulica);
pole[i][v-1] = '\0';
if (v - 1 > *max)
{
    *max = v;
}
i++;
}
return pole;
```

part of main where I am calling function

```
pole = function();
```

releasing memory

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < zaznamov; i++)  
{  
    free(pole[i]);  
    pole[i] = NULL;  
}  
free(pole);  
pole = NULL;
```

Comment: Don't cast the result of malloc.

Comment: Can you show a full example that fails?  In general, every call to `malloc` should be later followed with exactly one call to `free` so the code you're describing should work.  The bug is presumably in code you haven't yet told us about.

Comment: Show a [short, self-contained, compilable example](http://sscce.org/)!

Comment: Most likely it's crashing because you're writing out-of-bounds somewhere in your code, clobbering the metadata that malloc stores.

Comment: Please edit your question above instead of writing so much code in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Few things, you shouldn't cast the result of malloc.

```
char** alloc_2d_char(int rows, int cols) {
  char *data = malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(char));
  char **array= malloc(rows*sizeof(char*));
  for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
   array[i] = &(data[cols*i]);
 return array;
}
```

of course, you need to check for NULL's coming back from malloc

to free:

```
void free_2d_pixel(char **data){
  free(data[0]);
  free(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't show the full allocation code, it is hard to know what you're doing wrong.  Given what we see, you should have something like:

```
size_t n = 27;
size_t size = n * sizeof(char *);
char **arr = (char **)malloc(size);
size_t v = 39;

if (arr == 0)
    ...report error and bail out...

for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if ((arr[i] = (char *)malloc(v)) == 0)
    {
        // Out of memory — release what was already acquired
        for (size_t j = 0; j < i; j++)
             free(arr[i]);
        free(arr);
    }
}
```

And then for freeing the data:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    free(arr[i]);
free(arr);
```

You have to keep track on the number of elements in the array (`n` in my code) somehow.  Getting that wrong is problem.  So too is doing the freeing in the other order; releasing `arr` before the elements would be a bad mistake.

As for casting, or not casting, the return value from `malloc()`, as far as I'm concerned, it is up to you.  C++ demands it.  C used to require it in the days before standard C.  It does no harm as long as you always compile with options such that `malloc()` must be declared before you call it.  C99 demands that in strict conformance mode.  Make your compiler demand it.  I almost always use stringent compiler options to make sure that happens:

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror ...
```

If you're sloppy about this, don't cast `malloc()`.  If you're careful, you can cast if it suits you.